# Using Ruby on Rails to fetch and parse JSON from another web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, http, hash

I'm using Ruby on Rails to connect to various external web services, including Flickr, to receive some JSON data. I'd like to request this data and ideally, get it parsed into a arrays and hashes.

How does one get JSON data over HTTP and turn it into arrays and hashes using Ruby on Rails? Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try something like this

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

result = JSON.parse(open("url_of_json_service").read)
```

See more abut the JSON gem here: http://flori.github.com/json/

Answer (score 1):

I've never had to do this so these are just some ideas to look into...

If you're doing this from client side you could probably just make a JSONP request and manipulate the JSON object however you want.

Otherwise, if you want to make these calls from your server, you'd probably want to look into the [Ruby Net HTTP library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

Then to serialize and deserialize JSON you can use [this gem](http://flori.github.com/json/). It's the first one I found. There are probably others.

Comment: Of course I'm doing this server-side otherwise I wouldn't be talking about Rails. :)

Comment: I figured as much, I was merely suggesting that it would be pretty easy from client side as well, and you could probably even store the objects on your server with a POST if you had a model that fit the mapping.

Comment: @Bohdan Pohorilets: I hadn't seen that library yet. Looks nice!

Comment: Client-Side I'd have the problem of XSS. :(

Comment: @Time Machine: with AJAX, yes you would. Not with JSONP :)